# amqp protocol peer to peer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, amqp

I have tried to use amqpnetlite to send message peer to peer. I use this code: [amqpnetlite peer to peer](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite/tree/master/Examples/PeerToPeer). my question is: should I use an amqp broker for it?
here the exact code:

```
string address = "amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672";
Uri addressUri = new Uri(address);
ContainerHost host = new ContainerHost(new Uri[] { addressUri }, null, addressUri.UserInfo);
host.Open();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a broker for peer to peer communication. The ContainerHost you created is the listener. A client can connect to it and start sending/receiving messages.